# R convert character to dataframe column name and then replace values in a column

Tags: r, eval, assign

I was able to get content of the column pointed by character variable b. But i want to make column emp 0. How could i do that?

```
emp=c(1,2,30)
abc=data.frame(emp)
b="emp"
#below line gives content of column emp
eval(parse(text=paste("abc$", b, sep = "")))
#how can i replace each value in column emp with 0?
#below line doesnt work :(. It runs without error but values dont change 
assign((text=paste("abc$", b, sep = "")),0)
abc
```

Comment: And you can replace `eval(parse(text=paste("abc$", b, sep = "")))` with `abc$emp`

Comment: I guess, you have a specific reason to do things in such a complicated way?

Comment: i wont be able to do abc$emp as i am not going to be aware of the column name. The column name will change all the time and it will be stored in variable b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides trivial `abc[,'emp'] <- 0`, you can do:

```
eval(parse(text=sprintf('%s$%s <- 0','abc',b)))

abc
#  emp
#1   0
#2   0
#3   0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is almost never a good reason to use `eval(parse())`. The `$` syntax should only be used when you know the exactly name you want to extract. If you want to specify that value with a variable, use the `[,]` indexing method. For example

```
abc[, b] <- 0
```

or

```
abc[[b]] <- 0
```

The crazy assign doesn't work because `abc$b` isn't a variable. This is actually a function call similar to `'$'(abc, "b")`. You need to pass in the name of a variable to assign, not an expression.